# Is this Android FccTest App real and how do I remove it?

Tags: android

I have been removing unused Apps from my ZTE Zephyr Android phone and I see one called **FccTest** with the Force Stop and Disable buttons greyed out. It is not running. I wish to remove it, but there is no uninstall button. It has basically all privileges, but is not an Administrator.

The [FCC web site](https://www.fcc.gov/consumers/guides/fcc-speed-test-app-tip-sheet) says that its app can be removed by the user in the normal way. So is this not the real app, and in any case, how do I remove it? I have tried all approaches I can think of and read several web pages that did not give new info.

Comment: Unfortunately, if the apps is pre-installed by the manufacturer, they might locked the apps to prevent removal. You need to root your phone to get rid of it.